# If MOND requires fixes at LOW accelerations, why don't we see it in table experiments?

Tags: modified-gravity

`MOND` is controlled by

$\mu=\mu(\frac{a}{a_0})$

and

$\mu\rightarrow1$ when $a\rightarrow0$

But on my table $a=0$ so shouldn't I see `MOND` by just placing some weight on my weighter?

If it is wrong statement, then what do I need in my hypotherical lab to see `MOND` in table experiments?

---

The gravitational acceleration of a mass of one kilogram, induced on a probe mass at a distance of 1 meter is `G`, which is $10^{-11}$, i.e. much less than acceleration from a Galaxy, induced on a Sun, which is suffering from `MOND`.

I.e. `MOND` should be directly visible by measuring of attraction of two kilograms at 1 meter from each other.

Isn't it?

---

Regard two bodies of 1 kg, laying on table.

[image]

I agree, that the force $F_1$ is due to big gravity from Earth and hence MOND effects should be negligible. This force should be indistinguisheable from conventional gravity. But force $F_2$, induced by attraction of second body is very small. It is smaller, than attraction of a Sun from the Galaxy. Since Sun is the subject of MOND, then $F_2$ should also be `MOND`-affected. Once we measure it, we should immediately see, if `MOND` is correct or not.

Is there any error in this reasoning?

Answer (score 5):

On your table, the acceleration due to gravity is $a=9.8\ {\rm m/s^2}$, which you can't ignore in this context, and which is a lot larger than the MOND acceleration $a_0\sim 1.2 \times 10^{-10} {\rm m/s^2}$.

Even if you were in free fall around Earth, you couldn't ignore the acceleration of the Earth around the sun $\sim 6 \times 10^{-3}\ {\rm m/s^2}$ unless you could get outside of the Earth's gravitational field.

On the other hand, the acceleration of the sun around the center of the galaxy $\sim 1.7 \times 10^{-10}\ {\rm m/s^2}$. So if you could escape the Sun's gravitational field and do a high-precision gravity experiment, you could try to probe MOND this way. This fact was behind [attempts to explain the Pioneer anomaly using MOND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_anomaly#Definition_of_gravity_modified). However, the Pioneer anomaly is currently understood as due to the [thermal recoil force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_anomaly#Explanation:_thermal_recoil_force).

Comment: So, since `g` is gravitational field intensity, can we say tha `MOND` works in weak fields? Since fields of any mesoscopic bodies are weak, ergo any experiment measuring attraction of two kilograms (for ex) or smaller bodies will immideately confirm or reject `MOND`, right?

Comment: In the context of GR, weak field usually means you are well outside the Schwarzschild radius, and $ v \ll c $, or post newtonian is good enough. MOND is nano-gravity, or 1 billionth of a g.

Comment: @Dims If you could measure the attraction accurately between two kg masses that were outside of the gravitational influence of the Earth and Sun, then I suppose you could in principle look for MOND. But just to be clear this is very hard and unrealistic, and is not something you can do in a lab.

Comment: @Andrew do you mean `MOND` violates basic mechanical principles for example vector decomposition of forces and accelerations? I.e. if attraction of two kilograms acts horizontal it doesn't show `MOND` effects due to Earth acting, despite it acts vertical?

Comment: @JEB the acceleration, produced by a mass of 1 kilogram at a distance of one meters is of order of `G`, i.e. 10x-11, i.e. one hundredth of one billionth. So it is enough to see `MOND`.

Comment: @Dims I'm not sure what you mean but the MOND force law is not linear. In vector notation the law is $\vec{F}=m \mu(|\vec{a}|) \vec{a}$, where the interpolating function $\mu$ depends on the *magnitude* of the acceleration.

Comment: @Andrew in this form $|a|$ equals to zero while object is laying on table.

Comment: @Dims Do you have any references to back up your claim? I did a quick google search and found a 2014 review in NRC Research Press by A. Y. Ignatiev (https://cdnsciencepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/cjp-2014-0164) which backs up what I am saying (namely that $|a|\approx g$ for Earth-based experiments): "It is extremely important to clarify which reference frame
should be used for designing the MOND tests [3, 4]. The main point
is that the usual lab frame (i.e., frame fixed on the Earth) is not a
suitable one."

Comment: @Andrew `a` in Newton law is an "acceleration", it is the number of meters per second per second. If body is still, then `a` equals to zero, it's school or university knowledge. If `a` means something else, then explain please. This is why I am asking.

Comment: @Dims I'm sorry to put it like this but I know more than you do about this topic. I am volunteering my time to stack exchange, and it really does not incentivize me to help if you make snide remarks about "school or university knowledge." I've linked you to a reference that explains in detail this precise point. When you are applying the MOND force law, you can't ignore that the Earth is accelerating in its orbit around the Sun, for example. The acceleration is not zero.

Comment: @Andrew you asked for references about what is acceleration. Acceleration of staying body IS ZERO, sorry for saying that. I don't want to disregard you in any way.

Comment: @Andrew, so, do you mean, that any gravity, from any body, even if it is not acting on our experiment, will break `MOND`? 

It is automatically implies, that binary stars should not suffer from `MOND`, because their mutual gravity is big and should break `MOND` effects from the Galaxy. I.e. rotation curvers for binary stars should not be flat.

Is it true?

Comment: @Dims You can't turn off gravity, so every object on the Universe is acting on the experiment at least on some level. In Newtonian gravity, we can usually ignore these effects because they are so small. But the MOND acceleration scale is *tiny*, $10^{-10}\ {\rm m/s^2}$, so small accelerations that you would ignore in Newtonian gravity can have a big impact on the MOND force law (as footnote 2 in the paper I linked you to says, "Overlooking this point leads to a misguided perception that MOND has been already ruled out experimentally"). By the way, you should read that paper.

Comment: Anyway we shouldn't have too much more discussion in the chat, but I encourage you to ask a follow up question if this has led to more questions.

Comment: @Andrew sorry, but if I can't turn of gravity, then you also can't. Hence binary stars, which create big gravity for each other, should eliminate `MOND` effects. You can't regard only gravity from a Galaxy. Companion star is closer. Hence especially your number $\sim 1.7 \times 10^{-10}\ {\rm m/s^2}$ is incorrect for binary star.